# Selenium Server Automation - Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-rc, ui-automation

I am trying to run automation using Selenium Server and IE 11.
When I start ISelenium object using selenium.Start(), it throws a javascript error "object does not support property or method 'attachEvent'".

File path C:/Users/rlodha/AppData/Local/Temp/1/customProfileDir4d38c1e69384462995bae8b5362fd3b8/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js

Here is my code

```
public ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://www.google.com");
            selenium.Start();  //this line is throwing error
            selenium.Open("http://www.google.com");
```

I have IE 11 running with minimum security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't actually find any solution for IE browser but I switched to Firefox browser and didn't run into this error again.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium (*especially* RC) does not support IE11. This is the base of your issue. Either downgrade IE or use another browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">

if (typeof UserAgentInfo.strBrowser !== 'undefined'  && !window.addEventListener) {
    UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.

Comment: AS IE11 no more supports addEventListener the script error comes on every page load. to over come this in IE11 we are going to use above code.